# Why is a photo I set to be featured on my timeline not appearing on my timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I added a photo to my wall this morning. I then changed the date of the photo to December, 25th and set the photo to be a featured timeline item. Finally, I set the photo to be my cover photo. (Obviously, I really like the photo.)

Unfortunately, while the photo appears as my cover it does not appear in my timeline. When I double checked my activity it shows that I did indeed set the photo to be featured.

[image: picture of activity showing the picture as featured]

My timeline between December 24th and December 29th.

[image: image of timeline showing that the picture is not there]

How can I get the photo to appear on my timeline?

Comment: Did you check on Dec 25th on the timeline?

Comment: @phwd I added a picture of my timeline. No the picture is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to my profile (faceboook.com/myusername)

*Uploading a photo with a caption*

Currently the photo is set for Today (Jan 2nd) and appears on my timeline immediately.

*Changing the date*

This gave the notice

> This story will be moved to December 25, 2011 on your timeline.

Checking my feed (facebook.com) I see the story as

> phwd added a photo from December 25, 2011 to his timeline.

But the timeline link to it is unavailable. So I tried playing around with settings to see what could be the problem. When the date is fixed to the current date, it appears. When it is set in the past I am not sure where it goes.

*I think it is pretty safe to say this is a bug*

I gave in a bug report (May not do anything soon <sub>or ever</sub> but it's worth a shot)

Comment: About ten minutes ago the photo showed up. I think Facebook must be doing some caching and it only just now got refreshed. http://www.wired.com/wiredenterprise/2011/12/facebook-timeline-anatomy/